# MultiSite Administration for Drupal

Tags: multi-sites

We are a web development agency. In the past we've developed on Joomla, Wordpress and Drupal however we're becoming more Wordpress focused. We have systems such as InfiniteWP that we use to manage multiple sites with Wordpress installations and keep them up to date. This works really well for us as we can collect maintenance fees from our clients to keep plugins up to date and we can use a single admin login to be able to login to any of our WordPress sites.

I'm looking for a similar system for Drupal and as yet I haven't bee able to find a solution that offers me the same benefits as I can get with the other CMSs. At the moment, it's really only the one thing that's holding us back from dedicating more development resource to Drupal. Can anyone offer advice on a similar solution or how other companies are managing this issue.

Comment: The closest thing is [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/), but that has a bunch of its own problems and doesn't have SSO to all sites. Actually, having a single admin login for all websites should be considered a security threat, no?

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider it a security threat.. it's fairly common practice to use administration portals like this for other CMSs. The sites themselves still have their own logins and passwords they're just linked to a separate admin portal - no worse than having a password server that stores all the passwords.

Comment: Well, a little worse - password servers don't automatically try to log in to the services, they just store passwords. That's almost beside the point, though - in quite a few years of Drupal development I've never come across anything which does what you're looking for entirely

Comment: Thanks Clive - yeah, I understand there's obviously a degree of exposure but such a service makes administering sites and their content so much easier for a web agency like us. We have around 200 live clients who come to us with maintenance and development requirements for current installations - often times with a drupal installation it means adding a view or a new content type so being able to quickly access the site is a real convenience. Hopefully somebody has an idea or has something in development.